# Variables for JLabel will not center?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I am currently using a Absolute layout where I want to place a String variable to the panel (this frame is similar to a popup dialog) with horizontal alignment. Here's a snippet of my code.

```
JLabel label = new JLabel(loggedInAs);
label.setBounds(10, 61, 314, 23);
label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
contentPane.add(label);
```

When I run this the text appears to start slightly to the right, however if I enter preset text to the label such as

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("Hello");
```

it will center. Is there anyway I can resolve this?

(I have also played with the miglayout but it turned out completely different when running it from my main JFrame)

An example:

[image]

[Here is an example of what I mean by it being slightly to the right](https://gyazo.com/95f3543972b4250f76cb91a6d0a892be)

Comment: My be you have whitespaces, try `JLabel label = new JLabel(loggedInAs.trim());` make sure `loggedInAs` is not `null`

Comment: what's the value of `loggedInAs`?

Comment: @AlexandroSifuentesDíaz It is a string that changes depending on who logs in

Comment: For layout questions it's best to create and post an [mcve] and to post images (or links to images) of expected/desired and observed outcomes. It's also usually best to avoid absolute layouts.

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam This dialog only popups if the username matches those stored in our database, and when usernames are registered for the first time I have conditions that specify they can not be empty or have whitespaces or any non lettters

Comment: You can try: label .setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
label.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);

Comment: Being a *variable* is irrelevant; only the *value* (or object) supplied matters. So what is the *actual* [string] value/contents in these "not centered" cases?

Comment: @Rafiq If you looked at my code snippet you would have seen I have already tried those

Comment: @user286470 Anything I enter.....

Comment: @  Xh Lin not only  label .setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER); You can both are used:  label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER); label.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);

Comment: @Rafiq I tried this anyway and it didn't work :/

Comment: .......ahem.......... [mcve]

Comment: Why not simply use GridBagLayout?

Answer (score 4):

I think that your problem is in use of absolute layout, since you're using hard coded numbers to place your JLabel. The label text is itself centered fine, but if you put a border around the label, you'll likely see that the label itself, not its text, is skewed to the right. The easiest solution is to let the layout managers do the lifting for you. For example, the code below creates a successfully logged in dialog that uses a combination of layout managers to achieve what it looks like you're trying to do in your image:

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.Dialog.ModalityType;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class LoginPanelEg extends JPanel {
    private JTextField nameField = new JTextField(20);
    private Action LoginAction = new LoginAction("Login");

    public LoginPanelEg() {
        nameField.setAction(LoginAction);
        add(new JLabel("Login Name:"));
        add(nameField);
        add(new JButton(LoginAction));
    }

    private class LoginAction extends AbstractAction {
        public LoginAction(String name) {
            super(name);
            int mnemonic = (int) name.charAt(0);
            putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic); // alt-key comb
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            LoginPanel loginPanel = new LoginPanel(nameField.getText());

            Window win = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(LoginPanelEg.this);
            JDialog dialog = new JDialog(win, "Successfully Logged In", ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
            dialog.add(loginPanel);
            dialog.pack();
            dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            dialog.setVisible(true);
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("LoginPanelEg");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new LoginPanelEg());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class LoginPanel extends JPanel {
    private static final int PREF_W = 350;
    private static final int PREF_H = 200;
    private static final String SUCCESSFULLY_LOGGED = "Successfully logged in as:";
    private static final int GAP = 20;
    private static final Font PROMPT_FONT = new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.PLAIN, 14);
    private static final Font NAME_FONT = new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.BOLD, 12);
    private JLabel successfullyLoggedLabel = new JLabel(SUCCESSFULLY_LOGGED, SwingConstants.CENTER);
    private JLabel nameLabel = new JLabel("", SwingConstants.CENTER);

    public LoginPanel() {
        successfullyLoggedLabel.setFont(PROMPT_FONT);
        nameLabel.setFont(NAME_FONT);

        JPanel innerPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        innerPanel.add(successfullyLoggedLabel, createGbc(0, 0));
        innerPanel.add(nameLabel, createGbc(0, 1));

        JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel();
        btnPanel.add(new JButton(new CloseAction("Close")));

        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(GAP, GAP, GAP, GAP));
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(innerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(btnPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    }

    LoginPanel(String name) {
        this();
        nameLabel.setText(name);
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        nameLabel.setText(name);
    }

    private GridBagConstraints createGbc(int x, int y) {
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = x;
        gbc.gridy = y;
        return gbc;
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        }
        return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
    }

    private class CloseAction extends AbstractAction {
        public CloseAction(String name) {
            super(name);
            int mnemonic = (int) name.charAt(0);
            putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic); // alt-key comb
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Component component = (Component) e.getSource();
            if (component == null) {
                return;
            }
            Window win = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(component);
            if (win == null) {
                return;
            }
            win.dispose();
        }
    }
}
```